# Permission to my ~/.bashrc denied

Tags: bash

I have an issue with accessing my `~/.bashrc` file. I did and obtained the following:

```
yuve@YuveSys:~$ ~/.bashrc
-bash: /home/yuve/.bashrc: Permission denied
yuve@YuveSys:~$ sudo su
root@YuveSys:/home/yuve# ~/.bashrc
bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied
```

Can anyone help?

**NB**: I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.bashrc` is not meant to be executed but sourced. Try this instead:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

To edit the file run `nano .bashrc`

Hope it helps

Comment: I actually want to add a line of code in the .bashrc, that is to edit it.

Comment: The command nano .bashrc worked so i decided to post it here as an answer.

Comment: hey i am glad it helped you, anyways i was going to update my answer but its fine you have added it.

Answer (score 5):

If what you are trying to do is open the `.bashrc` file for editing, you need to open it with any text editor, such as nano, vi, or gedit. If you are trying to update after altering it in any way, you could use `source .bashrc` command.

For instance,

```
# Open the file with nano text editor and make changes you want
$ nano ~/.bashrc
# Run source command to apply changes
$ source ~/.bashrc
foobar@ubuntu:$
```

See also:

- [What is the difference between executing a Bash script vs sourcing it?](https://superuser.com/a/176788/418028)
- [How can I add a directory to PATH in a script so that it affects the calling shell and the rest of the session?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1073877/295286)

Answer (score 1):

`~/.bashrc` isn't supposed to be executed. You're supposed to run something like `gedit ~/.bashrc`

You're getting that error because the execute bit isn't set, but it shouldn't be.

You can also source it to edit by running `nano .bashrc` when you're in the root.